# New Podio Java API release on Maven

Tags: java, api, maven, podio

When is the new code on the Podio Java API released on Maven?

On the official API's github there is new code that hasn't already been released on Maven. It has been like this for almost one year and a half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wish I had a better answer for you, but we aren't actively updating or supporting our Java API at the moment. We are still discussing internally what this means for questions on this going forward.